# Base functionality for multiple descendants

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, abstract-class, derived-class

I have the following interface and classes hierarchy:

1. `IFunctionality` is an interface with a certain functionality. There are two implementations of this interface: `FDefault` (default implementation) and `FSpecific` (specific implementation).
2. Class `A` is a base abstract class and has a property of `IFunctionality` type. Since we have a default `IFunctionality` implementation, `A` creates an object of `FDefault` in the constructor and assigns it to the property.
3. Class `B` is derived from `A`, overrides non-`IFunctionality` functionality. It's not abstract. This class is OK with the default implementation of `IFunctionality`.
4. Class `C` is derived from `A`, overrides non-`IFunctionality` functionality. It's not abstract. This class is OK with the default implementation of `IFunctionality`.
5. Class `BSpecific` is derived from `B`. It requires the specific implementation of `IFunctionality`, that is `FSpecific`. It creates an object of `FSpecific` class and assigns it to the property.
6. Class `CSpecific` is derived from `C`. It requires the specific implementation of `IFunctionality`, that is `FSpecific`. It creates an object of `FSpecific` class and assigns it to the property.

Below is a sample code showing this design:

```cs
interface IFunctionality
{
}

class FDefault : IFunctionality { }
class FSpecific : IFunctionality { }

abstract class A
{
    protected A() { this.Functionality = new FDefault(); }

    public IFunctionality Functionality { get; set; }
}

class B : A { }

class C : A { }

class BSpecific : B
{
    public BSpecific() { this.Functionality = new FSpecific(); }
}

class CSpecific : C
{
    public CSpecific() { this.Functionality = new FSpecific(); }
}
```

The problem is that both classes `BSpecific` and `CSpecific` are making the same job, they both are responsible to create a new object of `FSpecific` class. Ideally I would like to create it only in one place. Is there a way to achieve that? Maybe the classes should be redesigned somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If B and C share functionality, but they don't share that functionality with A, you could consider another super class of B and C that inherits from A:

```
class SuperBC : A
{
    public SuperBC(){ this.Functionality = new FSpecific(); }
}
```

then, let B and C inherit from that class:

```
class BSpecific : SuperBC
{
    public BSpecific() : base() {}
}
```

Because you have B and C as well as BSpecific and CSpecific, you end up having to make that super class higher up your tree than you might want so you will probably face a trade-off between puzzling inheritance versus a small amount of duplicate code.

Comment: +1.  I was about to say, why not add an abstract class right below A.  Have the new abstract class inherit from A, except its constructor creates a Specific functionality object instead of the Default.

Comment: Classes `B` and `C` contain their specific functionality that is not related to `IFunctionality`, classes `BSpecific` and `CSpecific` in their turn inherit this functionality from `B` and `C` accordingly. Therefore `BSpecific` and `CSpecific` cannot directly derive from `SuperBC`.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments laid out in oerkelens answer, I think this is the 'Diamond Inheritance Problem' - basically, what you're asking for can't really be done in a language that only allows inheritance from a single object.  In this case, the top of the diamond is the A class, the left is the B class, the right is the 'Specific' class, and the bottom is the BSpecific class.  BSpecific wants to inherit from two different things - a 'B' class, and a 'Specific' class, but it can't, and 'B' and 'Specific' can't inherit from one another (not all B's are specific; not all specifics are B's.)

That said?  If you wanted to get *really* fancy, you could do something like this:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public IFunctionality Functionality { get; set; }
    public A()
    {
        Type t = GetFunctionalityType;
        Functionality = (IFunctionality)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
    protected virtual GetFunctionalityType { get { return typeof(FDefault); } }
}
public class B : A { }
public class BSpecific : B
{
    public override GetFunctionalityType { get { return typeof(FSpecific); }}
}
```

Honestly, though, unless the constructor gets complicated, just put it in both BSpecific and CSpecific.  What I *would* worry about is, in your code, you're creating an instance of FDefault *and* FSpecific whenever you create a BSpecific/CSpecific object (the FDefault is created in the base constructor, and is then replaced in the sub-class's constructor.)